# Can't install Rails. ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I try to install rails

```
sudo gem install rails
```

But i have the error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.5/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20191108-7794-8cwt0o.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.5/gem_make.out
```

My OS is Linux.
How can i fix it error?

UPD.
I managed to put the rails 4 versions, but they can not be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Nokogiri needs to be compiled so needs some C definitions to work.

Comment: same error? the output has not change?, i've updated that command, can you try again? (i added libxml2-dev)

Answer (score 0):

Do this first, install after that

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```